# How to get list of datastore using cluster name in vcenter rest?

Tags: python, api, vcenter

I've cluster name with me and I want to list out all datastore and available for that clusters using Vcenter rest API! Please tell me how can I do so?

I'm referring [VM Ware](https://developer.vmware.com/apis/vsphere-automation/latest/vcenter/api/vcenter/datastore/get/) website for this but am not able to find the solution.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Hello please check this link https://developer.vmware.com/apis/vsphere-automation/latest/vcenter/api/vcenter/datastore/get/ Make sure to get a session-id before call datastore api resource. https://developer.vmware.com/apis/vsphere-automation/latest/vcenter/authentication.html

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for responding!!
But Im still not able to filter datastores of particular cluster.